# Higher tangent bundles of manifolds with non integer dimension

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

One way to define the tangent space of a manifold at a point $p\in M$ is the following: We define an equivalent relation on the space of curves passing $p$ as follows: Two curves  $\alpha, \beta$ are equivalents iff they have tangencity of order at least one that is $\parallel \alpha(t)-\beta(t)\parallel=o(|t|)$, in a local smooth coordinate.

Then the tangent bundle is the disjoint union of these tangent spaces.

One can generalize this by increasing the order of tangencity, that is $\parallel \alpha(t) -\beta (t)\parallel=o(|t|^{k})$.

> Does the later gives us the $k-th$ tangent bundle? In this way, what would we get when $k$ is not an integer. For non integer $k$, do we get a well known structure(as a fiber bundle or some thing like this)?

Comment: (+1) Thank you for asking this. I had a similar question in mind long time ago but I never found its answer!

Comment: I am pretty sure this gives you a "jet bundle" not a higher order tangent bundle.

Comment: @StevenGubkin Thanks for your comment. We have a jet bundle for integer k, yes? but what about noninteger?

Comment: And another quibble: in the title you probably mean "noninteger order", not "dimension". For smooth curves the order of contact is always an integer. So you will be looking at curves which are actually not smooth. IMHO it maybe more worthwhile to think dually: instead of thinking about Holder continuous curves, perhaps a better approach is to see what happens if we try to define a locally ringed space based on $\mathbb{R}$ (for example) and its sheaf of $C^{0,\alpha}$ functions.

Comment: @WillieWong  Thank you for your comment. Can I ask you to expand your  comments in the form of an answer with more details?

Comment: The first half of my comment is nothing deep at all: basically just the definition of differentiable. The second half of my comment is just "random musing" and I have no more intelligent things to say about it. Sorry.